# I cannot import the PircBotx lib from Maven Repository with Gradle on Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Im migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio. So I wanna use the Gradle to import the [PircBotX](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.pircbotx%7Cpircbotx%7C2.0.1%7Cjar) lib from the maven.
But I get this message:

***Error (15, 13) Failed to resolve: org.pircbotx:pircbotx:2.0.1***

What is wrong? What should i do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle? Also, make sure that you have either jcenter() or mavenCentral() in your repositories.

Comment: Daniel, I already solve the problem. I was my project issue for migrating from eclipse to studio. Thanks.